# How to view,compare and refresh current time?

Tags: android, time

The aim of my current application is to get current time of my phone , compare it to a list of timerange that i've set and view the time remaining between my current time and the time range ( so I will need a refresh of the view each seconds ).

Example : Current time = 11 pm
          Time range A = 11:10 pm

I would like to view :

```
   x = 11h  
   A = 11h10min            

   view ( x); // refreshing each seconds 
   view ( A- x); // refreshing each seconds
```

For the moment I suceeded to view my current time with :

```
public class HoraireTempsReel extends Activity {

private TextView tvDisplayTime;
private int hour;
private int minute;
private String CurTime;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.horairetempsreel);

    setCurrentTimeOnView();
}

// display current time
public void setCurrentTimeOnView() {

    tvDisplayTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTime);


    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    // set current time into textview

    Resources CurTimeRes = getResources();
    CurTime = CurTimeRes.getString(R.string.CurTime,hour,minute);

    tvDisplayTime.setText(CurTime);


}
```

}

But I didn't suceed to get it refreshed every seconds.
I've done some researchs and i find out that using handlers may be a solution but the concept is a little bit hard to understand ( i'm a beginner in android dev ) so i would like to know if there is another way to resolve my problem.

( Sorry for my bad english , i'm not a native )

**Update :** 
Thanks for you answer Salauyou !

> First, it is a bad style to keep date-time variables in ints or
>   strings. There is specialized class in Java called Date for this
>   purpose.

Ok I will try to change as soon as possible .

> And don't rely on default locale!

What do you mean ?

> Now your timer is scheduled and will execute your
>   setCurrentTimeOnView() method every 1 second until you cancel it by
>   timer.cancel()

Ok i tried to adapt the code you give me to my program , it gives something like :

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.horairetempsreel);

        Timer timer = new Timer();  

        timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){  // set a TimerTask 
           @Override
           public void run(){            // override its run() method
              setCurrentTimeOnView();    
           }

        }, 0, 1000);    

}
```

I don't know where to put the timer.cancel() and it gives me an error on logcat :

**E/AndroidRuntime(7701): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.**